# jquery input value comparison only gets one digit

Tags: jquery, input, compare

hi im new to jquery and im facing these problem

i have these code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script>
$(".adults").change(function(){
    var test = $(".maxpeople").val();
    if ($(this).val() > $(".maxpeople").val()) {
        alert("test");
    }
    alert(test)
});
</script>
```

and i need to compare the digits and if the value of .adults is bigger than the value of .maxpeople then show me an alert.
the code works but it looks like it only takes one digit.
exjample:

.maxpeople = 17

i put 1 in .adults and is ok but if i put 2 it shows the alert, now if i put 16 it doesnt show the alert.. what im i doing wrong??

Comment: Use parseInt with a radix of 10 to explicitly cast your values as integers. Ex. `parseInt($(this).val(),10) > parseInt($(".maxpeople").val(),10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`val()` is going to return a string.  If you want to compare numbers, you will have to convert the strings to numbers.

Assuming you just want integers, use `parseInt`.

Comment: these is my link http://seo9.es/ibiza3/es/component/ibiza4rent/1?view=detalle&type=casas under  email the first to the right is the input and maxpeople is hidden

Comment: One important note, **always** pass the `radix` parameter (the 2nd parameter which tells it which base the numbers are in) or you will eventually run into some very odd issues with octal.

Answer (score 2):

The values are being treated as strings unless told otherwise

Try this:

```
$(".adults").change(function(){
    var test = $(".maxpeople").val();
    if (  parseInt($(this).val(),10) > parseInt($(".maxpeople").val(),10)) {
        alert("test");
    }
    alert(test)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare integers, not strings. Consider the following example:

```
console.log("12" > "2"); //false
console.log(12 > 2); //true
```

You should use the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to fix this, i.e:

```
var test = parseInt($(".maxpeople").val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` is going to be a string. You need to make it a number if you want numeric comparisons.

```
parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(".maxpeople").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is, that you are comparing strings.

Use parseInt(), or parseFloat()

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem originates from the fact that `.val()` returns a `string`. Use `parseInt()` like so:

```
if (parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($(".maxpeople").val())) {
    alert("test");
}
```